# How to build Xamarin.Forms iOS app with Azure Pipelines and F# 5

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, f#, xamarin.ios, azure-pipelines

I have a Xamarin.Forms app that I'm trying to build with an Azure DevOps Pipeline. The app uses the Fabulous F# MVU framework for Xamarin.Forms and therefore needs F#.

The Android version of the app compiles fine, both locally and on the pipeline. The iOS version of the app compiles fine locally in Visual Studio where I am using F# 5, but the build fails in the pipeline, complaining about a number of syntax errors. I think the reason for this is that the Mac pipeline build agent that I need to use for the iOS version is using F# 4.5 and not F# 5. I can see this output in the pipeline build log:

`Microsoft (R) F# Compiler version 10.2.3 for F# 4.5`

A sample syntax error would be:

`error FS1160: This token is reserved for future use`

The reserved token referred to is the `$` character being used to denote string interpolation. I guess that's not a thing in F# 4.5.

I have tried adding the "Use .NET Core" pipeline task to try and set the use of .NET 5.x, but the subsequent "Xamarin.iOS" pipeline build task does not seem to pick up on this.

How can I build this Xamarin.Forms iOS app in an Azure DevOps pipeline and make it use F# 5?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who runs across a similar problem: there was a script included in the pipeline (for only historical reasons now, from when we were using the MacOS 10.14 build agent image with an older version of the app) that set the Xamarin SDK to version 6.8.0. Disabling this script allowed the default Xamarin SDK version (currently 6.12.7) on the MacOS 10.15 build agent image to take over, and this solved my F# version problem.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I build this Xamarin.Forms iOS app in an Azure DevOps pipeline and make it use F# 5?

According to this [doc](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0), we could see that the `SDK 5.0.202` contains `F# 5.0`

And check this [doc](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md#language-and-runtime), we could see that the hosted agent `macos-10.15` has the `.NET SDK 5.0.202`

We need to specify the hosted agent in the Azure DevOps pipeline and add the task `Use .NET Core` to install the SDK version `5.0.202`, then we could use `F# 5.0` in the Azure DevOps pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have managed to get past the issue. I've added an answer for anyone coming by in the future.